# Search for contains Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, linq, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I need to search for contains in elasticsearch. I have the following query:

```
             .Query(q => q
                 .MultiMatch(a => a
                        .Fields(f => f
                              .Field(p => p.Attachment.Content)
                              .Field(p => p.FileName))
                        .Query(queryValue))));
```

And it's working fine but only for exact match. I want to search for contains, so if queryValue is contained in Attachment.Content or FileName I want to get the result.

Comment: How this is will work will depend on how `Attachment.Content` and `FileName` are analyzed and the definition of _"contains"_ here. It'd probably be useful to provide some example data, and an example query that you expect to return hits.

Comment: Hi @RussCam, thanks first of all. Attachment.Content and FileName are simple strings, for example Attachment.Content is "Test this is a text field" and FileName "document.pdf".